# spark2.0.1 - partition discovery failure

Tags: partitioning, parquet, apache-spark-2.0

I have the following parquet files in partitioned directories:

```
/files/dataset
  /id=1
       parquet.gz 
  /id=2
       parquet.gz      
  /id=3
       parquet.gz
```

In spark1.6 these can be accessed as follows:

```
val arr = sqlContext.read.parquet("/files/dataset/").collect
```

However in spark2.0.1 this code throws an error:

```
val arr = spark.read.parquet("/files/dataset/").collect


java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector.getLong(OnHeapColumnVector.java:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The individual partition directories can be read separately and unioned, but Im curious as to what discrepancies I should be looking for.

UPDATE: The partitioned directories were written via three separate writes, 
eg `df.where(id=1).write.parquet` instead of `df.write.partitionBy`. This appears to be the root of the problem. However I am actively trying to determine why the read/collect succeeds in the previous version of spark.

UPDATE: The 'id' column above is a Long, which when written explicitly (eg df.write.parquet('/files/dataset/id=1') throws errors during read. Partition discovery apparently attempts to read the partition as an IntType rather than a Long. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18108